# PgSql 14-Pgagent not connected with database

Tags: postgresql, pgagent, postgresql-14

Hi I am using PgSql 14 and I have installed it's relevant PgAgent from stack builder.

By using local and remote both are not connected to the database.
But the same job script working fine with PgSQL 12.3 and it's PgAgent.

What are the things needs to consider. Any error logs to check for PGAGENT?
Please give suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide diagnostics, error messages, configuration details and log messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.